# Compositional Data and Machine Learning

Tags: machine-learning, categorical-data, multivariate-analysis, data-transformation, compositional-data

One of my features is compositional of nature, represented by a vector `[p1, p2, p3]`. Each vector represents an emotion and each vector sums up to unity. Eg: `[anger=0.10, sad=0.10, happy=0.80]`.

1) I read about natural constraints of compositional data. What are these?

2) These constraints force us to transform compositional data using isometric/additive/centered logratio before they become useable, why is this necessary?

I know that for a lot of models, correlated features are ill-advised. Is this why we transform compositional data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Regarding the constraints**

You gave a good example of what a compositional data sample looks like. 
These 'natural constraints' as you call them are simply the restrictions on the sample space that compositional data implies.

A vector $\mathbf{x} = [x_1, x_2,...,x_D]$ must satisfy **two requirements** to fit into a 'compositional sample space', which is a D-dimensional simplex.

1. $x_i \geq 0 \: \forall \: i=1,...,D$ , that is all elements of the vector must be greater or equal zero
2. $\sum_{j=1}^{D}x_j=\mathcal{k}$, so all elements of $\mathbf{x}$ must sum up to $\mathcal{k}$, which is the 'total' of the composition. In your example this is 1, it could as well be 100, 1000 or any arbitrary number $\geq 0$.

**Why transformations are often used with compositional data**

As Aitchison states in ['The Statistical Analysis of Compositional Data'](http://leg.est.ufpr.br/lib/exe/fetch.php/pessoais:abtmartins:thestatisticalanalysisofcompositionaldata.pdf)

> "It is argued that the statistical analysis of such data has proved
>   difficult because of a lack both of concepts of independence and of
>   rich enough parametric classes of  distributions in the simplex."

Aitchison elaborates on approaches to analysis of data in the simplex, while on the other hand Egozcue et al. (ref. 3 below) proposed the isometric log-ratio transformation to transform the data from a D-dimensional simplex to $\mathbb{R}^{D-1}$, in which the application of conventional statistical methods becomes possible.

**Further references:**

1. [Short summary](http://www.sediment.uni-goettingen.de/staff/tolosana/extra/CoDaNutshell.pdf) of the most important concepts for compositional data analysis. I found this useful as a quick cheat sheet, but it does require some of the other two sources for initial understanding of the theory.
2. [Lecture notes](http://www.compositionaldata.com/material/others/Lecture_notes_11.pdf) on the topic of compositional data analysis.
3. [Egozcue et al.](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1023%2FA%3A1023818214614.pdf) went into a lot of mathematical detail to motivate the necessity of the ilr transformation, which I can't and won't replicate here.