# How to model choice among three quantities, subject to a constraint

Tags: regression, compositional-data

I have a response variable that is the amount in monetary units (m.u.) that a person can choose to donate among three alternatives, subject to a constraint that the total amount should be equal to 100 m.u.
More formally, I have n people who chose x, y and z, s.t. x >= 0, y >= 0 , z >= 0 and x + y + z = 100. I have a bunch of predictors at the level of the individual, but I am not sure how to build a regression model to predict x, y, and z.

The simplest approach is to model each variable (x, y, and z) separately. However, I'm throwing away a lot of information, since they're linearly dependent since in the experiment the person is asked to allocate the amount among the three alternatives.

Any ideas on how to model this problem? I was thinking that maybe I could build a generative Bayesian model for the choice, but I got struck and can't pass to the simplest approach delineated above.

Comment: You might want to read about Dirichlet regression

Comment: As Henrys comment hints at, your response variable is compositional and should be modeled accordingly. An [answer of mine regarding compositional data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/385068/20221) includes a reference that argues that transformations like the isometric log-ratio transformation can make standard statistical methods work with compositional data, too.

Comment: Awesome. I didn't know that the kind of data I was talking about is called compositional. This is exactly what I was looking for, since I didn't even know where to start, and now I know.